# Script Wi-Fi SSID switch if on SSID "X"

Tags: mac, network

I'm stuck on a script to switch a Mac to a different SSID ***if*** its already connected to a certain SSID.

What I need the script to do is:

Check what SSID the Mac Wi-Fi is using

If it is on SSID called "CompanyA" switch to SSID called "CompanyB"
If it is not on SSID called "CompanyA" do nothing.

I can get SSID currently connected to with

```
networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | cut -d ":" -f2
```

and I can switch with

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "CompanyB"
```

But I don't know how to do the ***if*** on CompanyA then switch to CompanyB

Answer (score 1):

Test (`[`) if the output of `networksetup` is the same as the string `CompanyA` if so then change the SSID to CompanyB.

```
curssid=$(networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | cut -d ' ' -f4-)

if [ "$curssid" = CompanyA ]
then
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "CompanyB"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
[[ $(networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | awk -F': ' '{print $2}') == "CompanyA" ]] && networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "CompanyB"
```